Align 3 elements in the column top center and bottom
I have a compose screen where I have a Text at the top and Button at the bottom of the screen. How can I fill the remaining space with other content?
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight().background(colorWhite)) {
    Text(
        text = "Heading",
        fontSize = 16.sp,
    )
}

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.background(color = White).wrapContentHeight().fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
) {
    // Remaining content
}

Button {}


@Preview
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp) // Optional padding
    ) {
        // title
        Text(
            text = "Heading",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
        )

        // Fills the remaining space
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.LightGray) // Example background color
        ) {
            // Add your other content here
            Text(
                text = "Middle Content",
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }

        // bottom button
        Button(
            onClick = { /* Handle button click */ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Bottom Button")
        }
    }
}


You can do it using the verticalArrangment parameter of the Column(). Here is an example. Kindly go through it.

Arrangement.SpaccBetween
Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
Arrangement.SpaceAround




The above 3 images describe the 3 different vertical arrangements. This is a sample example of how you can achieve the thing you want.
Beloved I mentioned the sample code. You need to change the value of verticalArrangement accordingly.
fun ComposeView() {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween, // Change accordingly
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(150.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(150.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(150.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)
        )
    }
}



There are more options than just the three, see the documentation. There is also an animated illustration that clearly demonstrates the differences.
